# Django MySQL Filter records on dates after adding duration to date

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm, pymysql

My Model (with attribute values):

```
MyModel:
    start_date = models.DateField()
    active_duration = models.IntegerField() 
    active_unit = models.CharField() # 'month' for month, 'year' for year
```

Let suppose, I want to filter all the records which are still active in the current month. To get this I am calculating the last  active date of a record that is calculated using duration and unit

```
MyModel.annotate(last_active_date=Case(When(
        active_unit='month', then=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('start_date') + timedelta(days=(F('duration_type'))), output_field=DateField())
    )))
```

But this is not letting me use F objects with timedelta I tried using relative_delta too.

Comment: Use [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#durationfield)

Comment: This is not going to help because timedelta does not support F() objects. we still need to incorporate active_unit